# Windows image viewer with sidebar for photos from different folders

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I'm transitioning from OSX to Windows 10. The transition is smooth except for one thing: The default image viewer in OSX, Preview, has more functionality regarding multiple folders.

In Preview, I can open a file from one folder and view it. I can open a file from another folder and view it as well. As I open a third, fourth, etc. file from different folders, thumbnails of the files I've opened appeared in a sidebar.

See this image for an example: 
[image]

This is a screenshot of Preview in OSX. Notice the four thumbnails in the left sidebar. All four images are from different folders. One image is from Costa Rica; another from Guatemala; another from Honduras; and a fourth in a folder named "Flowers." I can add a fifth image by just double-clicking the file in Finder. Very simple.

So far I've used Windows 10's default Photo app, IfranView, Fast Stone Image Viewer, and Picasa. All are great apps...if you're viewing a set of images in the same folder. If you're viewing from different folders, they're not useful.

Your suggestions?

Comment: Picasa can do this too.you jus have to add library's(Folders that contain those pics) to it first or set the hard drive to the default library then it ll automatically detect all the photos available in your drive.